# Nest within a Nest: XML Mapping

Tags: xml, sas

I am trying to reverse engineer the below XML extract in a mapping document using XPaths. The below data will be coming from a SAS dataset.

```
            <data1:Animal>
                <data1:AnimalDetails>
                    <data1:Name>Abcd</data1:Name>                       
                </data1:AnimalDetails>
                <data1:AnimalCondition>
                        <data1:ConditionType>YYY</data1:ConditionType>
                        <data1:SignsDescription>XXX</data1:SignsDescription>
                </data1:AnimalCondition>
            </data1:Animal>
            <data1:Parties>
                <data1:PolicyHolder>
                <data1:Type>PolicyHolder</data1:Type>
                    <data1:Person>
                        <data1:Title>Mrs</data1:Title>
                    </data1:Person>
                </data1:PolicyHolder>
            </data1:Parties>
```

I know it involves creating a nest within a nest. I am using the below code to get the PolicyHolder tag but not sure how to do the Person tag within the PolicyHolder Tag.

```
<COLUMN name="PETNAME">
<PATH syntax="XPath">/REQUEST/DATA/ANIMAL/ANIMALDETAILS/Name</PATH>
<TYPE>character</TYPE>
<DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
<LENGTH>30</LENGTH>
</COLUMN>

 <COLUMN name="condit_type">
<PATH syntax="XPath">/REQUEST/DATA/ANIMAL/ANIMALCONDITION/ConditionType</PATH>
<TYPE>character</TYPE>
<DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
<LENGTH>17</LENGTH>
</COLUMN>

<COLUMN name="signs">
<PATH syntax="XPath">/REQUEST/DATA/ANIMAL/ANIMALCONDITION/SignsDescription</PATH>
<TYPE>character</TYPE>
<DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
<LENGTH>40</LENGTH>
</COLUMN>


<COLUMN name="party_type">
<PATH syntax="XPath">/REQUEST/DATA/PARTIES/POLICYHOLDER/Type</PATH>
<TYPE>character</TYPE>
<DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
<LENGTH>13</LENGTH>
</COLUMN>

<COLUMN name="TITLE">
<PATH syntax="XPath">/REQUEST/DATA/PARTIES/POLICYHOLDER/PERSON/Title</PATH>
<TYPE>character</TYPE>
<DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
<LENGTH>5</LENGTH>
</COLUMN>
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
<ANIMAL>
<ANIMALDETAILS>
<Name>Abcd</Name>
</ANIMALDETAILS>
<ANIMALCONDITION>
<ConditionType>YYY</ConditionType>
<SignsDescription>XXX</SignsDescription>
</ANIMAL>
<PARTIES>
<POLICYHOLDER>
<Type>POLICY HOLDER</Type>
<PERSON>
<Title>MRS</Title>
</ANIMALCONDITION>
</PERSON>
</POLICYHOLDER>
</PARTIES>
```

The `</AnimalCondition>` tag is in the wrong place and should be before `</Animal>`

How do I fix this and ensure the closing tags are in the right place.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you.

Comment: Does `<PATH syntax="XPath">/REQUEST/DATA/PARTIES/POLICYHOLDER/Type</PATH>` actually work - that is, it gets `PH` into the column?

Comment: Hi Jack, Yes that line works and gets PH into <Type> node. The issue i get is, using the same format, if i do <PATH syntax="XPath">/REQUEST/DATA/PARTIES/POLICYHOLDER/PERSON/Title</PATH> and so on, the </Person> end tag ends AFTER the </POLICYHOLDER> end tag.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Please edit the question with examples of what you try, the actual output and the desired output; that should help.

Comment: Jack, I hope the above helps